# How can I get a stable result set for my REST API without an order by clause or a cursor?

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, database-cursor, rds-data-api

I am creating a REST API that connects to an AWS RDS instance (Aurora Serverless/Postgres) using the RDS Data API. The request flow:
`Client -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> RDS Data API -> RDS`

The Lambda maps the request to a sql statement which is sent to RDS via the Data API. The results (rows) of the query are sent back to the client in json format.

All my tables have an indexed primary key column. However the value of this primary key does not always increment by 1, there are gaps. The tables can contain up to a couple billion rows.

The solution is simple for smaller tables, but for larger tables some sort of pagination has to be implemented due to Data API limits (1 MB response size) and Lambda runtime limits (max 15 minutes). I have read about different methods to implement pagination. The only suitable method seems to be cursor-based pagination, as it's the only method that can guarantee a stable result set without using an `order by` clause.

However I can't use (server side) cursors because when the Lambda times out, the database connection gets closed, as well as the cursor.

I could use url parameters containing a start and an end value to filter the primary key column of the table, however this column does not always increment by 1. So doing something like `https://website.com/table/users?start_idx=0&end_idx=100` would not necessarily return 100 records, which is undesirable.

How can I best solve this in an idiomatic manner?

Comment: You cannot do that without an `ODER BY`.

Comment: no way to do it without ORDER BY, you must also use OFFSET and LIMIT. even cursor-based pagination is not the solution since a cursor needs a open connexion, the cursor is lost one's the connexion is closed.

Comment: I think I will then just add a true incremental key column to each table and use start and end url parameters in the where clause. If this column is indexed it should be a lot faster than using `order by` and offset/limit.